# Как писать простейшие UnitTest'ы к простейшим функциям?

Tags: java, android, юнит-тесты, junit

Хочу научиться писать тесты для своих проектов.

Подскажите какие-нибудь хорошие ресурсы, чтобы научиться тестировать Android приложения.

Насколько важно их использование?

Сейчас я пишу приложение без их использования и пока не могу оценить их пользу.

Те коды, которые встречаю в интернете, не помню, чтобы где-то в коде встречал тесты.

В общем, хочу понять, что это значит. Подскажите, с чего начать.

Допустим есть вот такой метод:

```
private File getFile(File path) {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    return new File(path.getPath() + File.separator + timeStamp + ".html");
}
```

Как можно к нему написать тест и что нужно для этого сделать?

**ПРАВКА**

Вот кстати есть ссылка с видео где показан пример теста

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZJE0MDKJOow

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Для того чтобы создать юнит тест, вам прежде всего нужно определиться что вы собственно собираетесь тестировать. В идеале, ваш метод должен делать что-то одно и тогда ваша задача упрощается. Если возможно, то юнит тест должен тестировать метод как черный ящик, то есть, вы подаете что-то на вход и проверяете полученное значение. К сожалению это не всегда возможно.

В вашем конкретном случае, первое что бросается в глаза, это то что метод помечен как `private`, такой метод нельзя тестировать стандартными методами. Существует много теорий насчет того нужно ли тестировать приватные методы или нет. Мое мнение - их можно не тестировать. Правильность работы приватных методов будет проверена неявно когда вы тестируете все открытые методы. Хотя если вы очень хотите то можно пометить метод как 'default' (убрать тип доступa), или можно использовать reflection.

Но допустим ваш метод публичный, тогда анализируя код понимаем, что метод возвращает новый файл с именем построенным из пути и функции текущей даты. То есть, он делает два действия:
* Создает имя файла
* Создает собственно файл
Тестировать его в текущем виде можно но не интересно. Я бы посоветовал немного поправить ваш код чтобы он был более пригодным для тестирования:

```
public File getFileFullName(File path, Date date) {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String fullPath = path.getPath() + File.separator + timeStamp + ".html";
    return fullPath;
}

// где-то в вашем коде
String path = ...
Date now = new Date();
String fileFullName = getFileFullName(path, now);
File file = new File(fileFullName);


// тест для метода getFileFullName в классе ClassUnderTest
@Test
public void testGetFileFullName() {
    String path = "/abc";
    Date date = new Date(1465953124); //2016-06-15 13:12:06

    ClassUnderTest instance = new ClassUnderTest()
    String name = instance.getFileFullName(path, date);

    assertEquals("/abc/20160615_131206.html");
}
```

Но вы можете спросить, а как тестировать код где мы создаем дату или используем файл? Касательно даты, я бы рекомендовал вообще не использовать new Date() в коде. Вместо этого использовать что типа провайдера или сервиса для получения текущей даты/времени. Тогда вы можете подменять реализацию этого класса для тестирования. Простейшая реализация может быть синглтон:

```
public class DateTimeUtils {

    private static DateTime fixedTime;

    public static DateTime getCurrentDateTime() {
        if (fixedTime == null) {
            return new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);
        }
        return fixedTime;
    }
    public static void useFixedCurrentTime(DateTime timeToReturn) {
        fixedTime = timeToReturn;
    }
}
```

Что касается объекта File то здесь вам поможет подмена классов с помощью мокирования. Посмотрите Mockito или PowerMock.

Еще маленькое дополнение. Если бы вы использовали test-driven development то такой проблемы бы не было.

Comment: А что скажите насчет тестов Robolectric? Вроде советуют их использовать...

Comment: И может из литературы, что то посоветуете?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko из литературы советую вот эту книгу http://bit.ly/28No5qY
Robolectric можно использовать для тестирования методов, где используются android классы, например TextUtils.isEmpty(). Для таких вещей роболектрик предоставляет реализацию, так как чистый junit вообще ничего не знает об андрод классах.

Answer (score 22):

Гораздо проще писать тесты для ещё не написанного кода(разработка через тестирование), нежели пытатся приделать тесты к готовому. Просто посмотрите на задачи, опишите проверки их выполнения в виде тестов, и только потом напишите код, который эти тесты успешно выполнит. Не полностью для всего проекта, а максимально небольшими шагами, состоящими из постановки задачи, написания теста и рабочего кода к нему.

Придумывание тестов к готовому коду - очень ресурсозатраная задача. Как в плане планирования(вам нужно вспомнить или выяснить зачем рассматриваемый код вообще был написан), так и в плане реализации(обычно нужен рефакторинг, много-много рефакторинга). Созданные "постфактум" тесты порой оказываются бесталковыми, написанными просто ради "близкого к 100% покрытия", а на деле не проверяющими то, что действительно стоило бы проверять...

Чаще всего оказывается дешевле и быстрее просто постепенно заменять старые модули новыми, написанными с нуля через тестирование, нежели писать тесты к уже имеющимся.

Comment: Я пробовал начинать читать книгу `Разработка через тестирование`, но на тот момент вообще не понял что за изощренный подход это такой... Насколько я понял, что таким образом очень снижается скорость разработки... От сюда вопрос, нужно ли писать все через тесты или только какие то части? Если части то как определять какие? И что вы думаете о тестах  Robolectric для андроид?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, очень много книг с так переведенным на русский названием - ссылаясь на книги, желательно указывать автора. Разработка через тестирование сильно замедляет разработку проектов-прототипов сделанных "за полчаса", изначально не предпологающих развитие проекта в будущем.

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, В остальных же случаях, когда в проект нужно долго развивать, и/или разрабатывать коммандой - разработка через тесты сокращает ресурсозатраты, т.к. практически полностью исчезает этап отладки(тесты выполняют эту задачу проще и эффективнее), и предварительное планирование архитектуры(архитектура выстраивается как будто сама, в процессе. однако всё равно, нужно понимания теории, что бы применять элегантные решения в нужных ситуациях), плюс тесты обычно очень хорошо документируют код(каждый тест - полноценный пример использования вашего кода в реальной ситуации).

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, по Robolectric - довольно занятный проект, позволяющий не использовать эмулятор/реальные устройства при разработке через тестирование. Никогда не использовал его, если честно. Но основной минус такого подхода - на некоторых задачах возможно будет расходится поведение Robolectric и настоящего/эмулируемого устройств, и тесты будут выдавать некоректный результат. Хотя всё зависит от того, насколько хорошо написан Robolectric - вполне возможно такихе расхождения незначительны, или даже вообще отсутствуют. Надо пробовать его в живых проектах, в общем.

Comment: вообще в роболектрик нужно тестировать бизнес логику, не больше. все что связано с циклами открытиями/закрытиями фрагментов/активити и прочими UI штуками лучше выносить в instrumentation тесты. TDD подход только по началу снижает скорость разработки, если правильно построить архитектуру приложения и четко разделить бизнес логику и UI, то написание бизнес логики может проходить чисто на тестах, можно даже ни разу не запустить приложение и сказать с уверенностью, что отдельные модули работают 100% правильно