# Как проверить работу Web-приложения

Tags: сервер, тестирование

Есть Web-приложение. Функций у этого приложения много. Собрал сам. Теперь хочу протестировать приложение перед его финальным запуском. Приложение работает проверял сам и все хорошо. Но как правильно проверять? Есть же спец инструменты для этого (скорее всего). Я тестирую так: запустился, работает, не тормозит. Наивный метод:) Но как проверить скорость сервера под нагрузкой, работу всяких функций и т.д.?

Использую `IDE NetBeans` и `JSF`

PS: этот вопрос не может быть спорным. Не надо махаться руками и т.д. Просто даете направления а я сам уже исследую.

Comment: А что за приложение?Можно ссылочку

Comment: Это для компании сервер .ссылкой поделиться немогу извените

Comment: "Проверка приложения перед финальным запуском" - это не юнит тесты. Есть как минимум два вида тестов (на самом деле гораздо больше, но это пусть вам тестировщики расскажут). Юнит тесты - это тест того что некий небольшой кусочек работает правильно и функциональные - что продукт и новые фичи в контексте продукта работают правильно. С точки зрения программиста а не qa стоит разобраться в первую очередь с юнит тестами (tdd хотя бы как подход понимать, не обязательно практиковать)

Comment: "Чего-то хочу, а чего -- не знаю сам" (С) Перефразируйте вопрос, чтобы можно было на него ответить. Вы хотите нагрузочное тестирование (так это называется) или юнит-тесты писать?  Разговоры "в общем" -- лучше в веб-чатик: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50668/web

Comment: @AK лучше в общий: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--, в вебочат никто не ходит) Если что разроутим

Comment: Во что я нашел про юнит тесты: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/534351/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B5-unittest%D1%8B-%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC/535105#535105, а так статей уйма

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нагрузочное и функциональное тестирование можно сделать при помощи [JMetre](http://jmeter.apache.org/). **JMeter** это очень мощный инструмент он позволяет:

- описать сложные сценарии взаимодействия пользователя с сайтом
- собрать информацию о времени ответа
- запустить несколько копий себя на разных компьютерах
- создать отчет о результатах работы тестов

В нем так же встроена IDE, которая позволяет быстро создавать тестовые сценарии. Думаю, что это то, что вы ищете.

Comment: Спасибоооооооооо!!!около 10 людей высмеяли меня и только один отвтил по теме!спасибо

Comment: JMeter QA тоже есть ? я думал он только для нагрузки

Comment: Да. JMeter можно использовать и для функционального тестирования, хотя это и не лучший выбор. Про отдельную QA версию не слышал.